# Реализация ANTLR-визитора и разбор идентификаторов, написанных через точку (C++ target)

Tags: c++, парсер, лексический-анализатор, antlr

Пытаюсь написать визитор, который разбирает некоторое выражение и возвращает тип данного выражения. За основу взяла грамматику [отсюда](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cpp).
Идея в следующем: при посещении правила literal, реализация такая:

```
    std::any CPPExpressionVisitor::visitLiteral(
        CPP14Parser::LiteralContext* ctx)
    {
        if (ctx->BooleanLiteral())   { return TI<bool>(); }
        if (ctx->CharacterLiteral()) { /**/ }
        if (ctx->FloatingLiteral())  { return TI<double>(); }
        if (ctx->IntegerLiteral())   { return TI<int>(); }
        if (ctx->PointerLiteral())   { return TI<nullptr_t>(); }
        if (ctx->StringLiteral())    { return TI<std::string>(); }
        assert(false && "TODO");
    }
```

TI< T>() - возвращает std::type_index (временно, т.к. в будущем хочу реализовать возможность добавлять пользовательские типы).

При посещении арифметических операций, например, такая реализация:

```
    std::any CPPExpressionVisitor::visitAdditiveExpression(
        CPP14Parser::AdditiveExpressionContext* ctx)
    {
        if (ctx->multiplicativeExpression().size() == 1)
            return visit(ctx->multiplicativeExpression()[0]);

        auto out = TI<int>();
        for (auto& multExpr : ctx->multiplicativeExpression())
        {
            auto res = visit(multExpr);
            auto typeind = std::any_cast<std::type_index>(res);
            // TODO
            if (is<double>(typeind))
                out = TI<double>();
            else if (is<float>(typeind))
            {
                if (!is<double>(out))
                    out = TI<float>();
            }
            else
                assert(is<int>(typeind));
        }
        return out;
    }
```

И так далее. Правила будут добавляться, но надеюсь, идея понятна.

Вопрос в следующем: возникли трудности при разборе идентификаторов, написанных через точку.
Например, выражение 'a.b.c.d' разбирается в следующее дерево:
[image: пример дерева]

Для правила postfixExpression добавлены метки, чтобы сгенерировались функции для каждой альтернативы:

```
postfixExpression:
    primaryExpression                                                           # postfixExpressionPrimary
    | postfixExpression LeftBracket (expression | bracedInitList) RightBracket  # postfixExpressionBrackets
    | postfixExpression LeftParen expressionList? RightParen                    # postfixExpressionFunction
    | (simpleTypeSpecifier | typeNameSpecifier) (
        LeftParen expressionList? RightParen
        | bracedInitList
    )                                                                           # postfixExpressionbracedInitList
    | postfixExpression (Dot | Arrow) (
        Template? idExpression
        | pseudoDestructorName
    )                                                                           # postfixExpression5
    | postfixExpression (PlusPlus | MinusMinus)                                 # postfixExpressionInccDecr
    | (
        Dynamic_cast
        | Static_cast
        | Reinterpret_cast
        | Const_cast
    ) Less theTypeId Greater LeftParen expression RightParen                    # postfixExpressionCast
    | typeIdOfTheTypeId LeftParen (expression | theTypeId) RightParen           # postfixExpression8
    ;
```

Так вот, при посещении обычного идентификатора я ищу имя в текущем контексте. Но как дать понять, что поиск надо проводить в другом контексте? Т.е после посещения идентификатора 'a' (правило unqualifiedId), при посещении 'b' искать это имя в контексте 'a'?
Я понимаю, что переключение контекста должно произойти в visitPostfixExpression5(), но как это сделать не знаю. И что должна вернуть функция unqualifiedId() при посещении 'a' или 'b' (т.е. промежуточного идентификатора)?

Правильно ли я сделала выбор выбрав реализацию через визитор? Реализация через листенер мне кажется будет громоздкой. Это мой первый опыт разбора грамматики, поэтому критика тоже приветствуется.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139801/discussion-on-question-by-milla--antlr----).